# Slow Printing A Variable In Python

Tags: python

I was coding a chatbot in python, and I came upon a small issue. I had the user type in their name, and then I had the chat bot print it out using this:
"user = input("What's your name?\n")
print(name_list)"
I was wondering if there is a way to make the chat bot type out the name slowly so that it looks like it's trying to figure the spelling out and think about it

Comment: Print it one character at a time in a loop, with calls to `time.sleep()` between them.